# Proving piecewise function is not Riemann integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

How would you prove that $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l} \pi, & \text{if $x$ is rational}, \\ 1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}. \end{array} \right.$ 
is not Riemann integrable

What I did is look at the Riemann sum when all the $x_i$ in the partitions are rational, and when they are irrational. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct. More formally: since $\mathbf{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}$, we have that $\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)=\pi$ and $\inf_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)=1$ on any interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]\subset\mathbf{R}$, therefore the upper and lower sums don't converge to the same limit. Hence $f$ is not Riemann-integrable.

---

Consider the partition $P=\{a=x_1<\cdots<x_n=b\}$ of an interval $[a,b]$.

For the upper sum, we have $$U(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \color{blue}{\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)}\cdot (x_{i+1}-x_i)=\color{blue} \pi\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)=\pi(b-a),$$
while the lower sum evaluates to

$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \color{blue}{\inf_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)}\cdot (x_{i+1}-x_i)=\color{blue} 1\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)=b-a.$$
Since $\pi(b-a)\neq b-a$, we conclude that $U(f)\neq L(f)$ therefore $f$ is not (Riemann-)integrable (on any interval $[a,b]$).

Comment: To rae306: +1. To OP: Note that rae306 is using a characterization of Riemann integrability called Darboux condition.

Comment: When I did the Reimann sums for the irrationals I got $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ and for the rationals i got $\pi \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is it enough to say that these limits are not the same considering that they are harmonic sums?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt I added some new information

Comment: the thing is we have not yet learned Darboux Integration so I wouldn't be able to apply it

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Each subinterval $F_i=[x_i,x_{i+1}] $ of a subdivision $\sigma $ of $[a,b] $, contains a lot of rationals and irrational reals.

thus

$$\sup_{x\in F_i}\{f (x)\} (x_{i+1}-x_i)=\pi (x_{i+1}-x_i) $$

and
$$U(f,\sigma)=\pi (b-a) $$